# How to perform updates on newly created rows within the same transaction?

Tags: postgresql, update, cte, bulk-insert, postgresql-13

Fiddle link: https://dbfiddle.uk/EOE627Oa

### Tables

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  login text NOT NULL,
  password text NOT NULL,
  email text,
  init_index bigint,
  parent_id bigint REFERENCES accounts
);
```

### Input data

```json
[
  {
    "login": "11EB19631A",
    "password": "AE128AADEF97F1E54021",
    "reference_id": 1
  },
  {
    "login": "3ED4ECBBC9",
    "password": "E67EDDB6033D02140BB4",
    "email": "a@b",
    "reference_id": 2,
    "parent_reference": 1
  },
  {
    "login": "C86D7E2CF0",
    "password": "75404617C000A0EB070C",
    "reference_id": 3,
    "parent_reference": 2
  },
  {
    "login": "C51D77BF87",
    "password": "605509993A05EE393081",
    "email": null,
    "reference_id": 4,
    "parent_reference": 2
  },
  {
    "login": "2BAB5AA533",
    "password": "DFCAB818D812B1F8F761",
    "reference_id": 5,
    "parent_reference": 3
  },
  {
    "login": "4229D47E2C",
    "password": "CE4E14ED6AD77CBC71B5",
    "email": "b@c",
    "reference_id": 6,
    "parent_reference": 2
  }
]
```

### Query

```
WITH account_inits AS (
  SELECT
    row_number () OVER () as init_index,
    login,
    password,
    email,
    reference_id,
    parent_reference
  FROM
    json_to_recordset(
      $json$$json$
    ) AS input_init(
      login text,
      password text,
      email text,
      reference_id int,
      parent_reference int
    )
),
-- create new accounts
new_accounts AS (
  INSERT INTO accounts
    (
      init_index,
      login,
      password,
      email
    )
  SELECT
    init_index,
    login,
    password,
    email
  FROM
    account_inits
  RETURNING
    *
),
parent_id_pairs AS (
    SELECT
      new_accounts.id,
      account_inits.reference_id
    FROM
      new_accounts
      INNER JOIN
      account_inits
      ON
        account_inits.reference_id IN (
          SELECT DISTINCT
            parent_reference AS reference_id
          FROM
            account_inits
        )
        AND
        new_accounts.init_index = account_inits.init_index
),
account_updates AS (
  SELECT
    new_accounts.id,
    parent_id_pairs.id AS parent_id
  FROM
    new_accounts
    INNER JOIN
    account_inits
    ON
      account_inits.parent_reference IS NOT NULL
      AND
      new_accounts.init_index = account_inits.init_index
    INNER JOIN
    parent_id_pairs
    ON
      account_inits.parent_reference = parent_id_pairs.reference_id
),
updated_accounts AS (
  UPDATE
    accounts
  SET
    parent_id = account_updates.parent_id
  FROM
    account_updates
  WHERE
    account_updates.id = accounts.id
  RETURNING
    *
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  updated_accounts
;

SELECT
  id,
  init_index,
  parent_id
FROM
  accounts
;
```

### The problem

The table in question has a foreign key to itself to express a tree-like relationship between its rows. But these relations can be known even before inserting within batch. Therefore `reference_id` and `parent_reference` are "batch identifiers" which are generated by the application to show the references between initializers.

However the database cannot express this relation in the `INSERT` statement for obvious reasons. So I thought about running a separate `UPDATE` step in a CTE for newly created rows. But it doesn't work, despite all input data being right (you can check that by `SELECT`'ing the CTEs used in the `UPDATE` CTE), so the problem is in the `UPDATE` block itself. The [docs list two different syntaxes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-update.html) for performing an `UPDATE` from a set of records. I tried both of them and neither apply the `parent_id` to the created rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask for updates ...

> within the same transaction

But, more specifically, you are trying to do it **within the same command**, which makes all the difference.

#### Solution

Long story short:

```
WITH account_inits AS (
   SELECT nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.accounts', 'id')) AS id, *  -- !!!
   FROM   json_to_recordset($your_json_input)
   AS input_init(login text, password text, email text, reference_id int, parent_reference int)
   )
INSERT INTO public.accounts
        (id,   login,   password,   email,   parent_id) OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE  -- !!!
SELECT a.id, a.login, a.password, a.email, p.id                     -- !!!
FROM   account_inits a
LEFT   JOIN account_inits p ON p.reference_id = a.parent_reference  -- !!!
RETURNING *;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l7xOJkD7)

That's all. Note added details in the simplified fiddle.

This assumes **referential integrity** within each inserted batch: any `reference_id` that is actually referenced by a `parent_reference` must uniquely exist in the batch.

#### Why? How?

The main problem of your original attempt is explained here

- [Why can't rows inserted in a CTE be updated in the same statement?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151199/why-cant-rows-inserted-in-a-cte-be-updated-in-the-same-statement/151217#151217)

The solution would be to run separate statements (within the same transaction). But don't go there. Use the **much simpler** approach as suggested: Fetch new serial IDs from the sequence with [`nextval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) beforehand. A `LEFT JOIN` to self does the rest.

Related:

- [INSERT rows in two tables preserving connection to a third table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160674/insert-rows-in-two-tables-preserving-connection-to-a-third-table/160825#160825)
- [For each row create a linked row in another table with auto-generated ID](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/317343/for-each-row-create-a-linked-row-in-another-table-with-auto-generated-id/317348#317348)

Since your `id` is `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` we must use [`OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.6.2) as demonstrated. See:

- [PostgreSQL How to DEFAULT Partitioned Identity Column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/225392/postgresql-how-to-default-partitioned-identity-column/225393#225393)
- [INSERT duplicate rows for multiple, cascading 1:M child tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/292199/insert-duplicate-rows-for-multiple-cascading-1m-child-tables/292315#292315)

Comment: How do these preemptive ID generations interact with foreign key checks? Does the order of insertions matter in this case, since there can be a situation where a row is inserted with a parent ID of the row which isn't inserted yet.

Comment: @BillerBuilder: Since all is inserted in a single command, FK constraints are no problem. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24816197/939860 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68245259/939860

Comment: Wow the `next_val()` approach sure reduced a lot of back-and-forth boilerplate joins in my query.

Comment: And you can save yet another underscore! `nextval()` :)